# Where can one find data on users' voting?

Tags: discussion, voting, statistics

I suspect, but it's only a suspicion, that I more frequently up-vote, and less frequently down-vote, questions and answers on "main", than does any other user with a substantial "reputation".

Where can one find hard data on this?

Comment: [User lhf](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/589/lhf)  has both more upvotes and less downvotes than you do.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : If you know that, then you quite probably you also know the answer to the question posted above.

Comment: I think Jyrki already answered your (original) question....more...than does **any** other user with substantial "reputation."

Comment: You can find this information by checking the profile pages of all the candidates. There aren't too many [users with 20000+ votes](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all). My stats are more or less similar to yours actually. I used to boast an even higher upvote/downvote ratio. But, a downside to moderating is that you are forced to wade through a lot of crap. It takes its toll.

Comment: @amWhy : That wasn't the question. The question was the sentence that ends with the question mark.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : When I click on "voters", I find "26217 votes" under "Davide Giraudo", but it doesn't say how many are up-votes and how many are down-votes.

Comment: Well, you have been ranting quite a bit lately.  If all you wanted to know were "the facts, ma'am, nothing but the facts, then why did you need to claim to be the highest upvoter, lowest down-voter, etc. Many may not see such a boast as anything to be proud about.

Comment: [Martin Sleziak](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/8297/martin-sleziak) also has more upvotes than either of us (and less downvotes).

Comment: @amWhy : I didn't want to "claim" to be that; rather I wanted to _find out_. As for "ranting", I have posted comments and feature requests that are inconsistent with the rigidly enforced orthodoxy that prevails on "meta". Disagreement with enforced orthodox views is called "ranting" here.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : So where do you find up-votes and down-votes rather than something that just says "26217 votes"?

Comment: Stop playing the martyr, @MichaelHardy.  It gets old.  I'm done here.

Comment: Michael Hardy, I told you to click the user's profile. The numbers are given right there. Scroll to the very bottom.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : I don't see anything like that in Davide Giraudo's profile. I enter control-f for "find", then in the search box I enter "votes", and I find data on the votes on his postings, but nothing on votes he has cast.

Comment: @Michael Click on 'Activity'. It is then listed at the very bottom - to the right - of the page under 'Votes Cast'.

Comment: @Stefan : Found it.  Hardly what I would call "right there", since you never see it until you scroll all the way to the bottom. Perhaps you could post this as an answer.

Answer (score 10):

[Data explorer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) is a good tool to find various statistics about SE sites. You can find various already existing queries ordering users by [percentage of downvotes](https://www.google.com/search?q=downvotes+percentage+site:data.stackexchange.com).

I took [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/153873/user-list-downvotes-and-percentage) and modified it to restrict to users [above a given reputation](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/606739/biggest-downvoters). And judging by your question, you are more interested in users with highest percentage of upvotes: [Biggest Upvoters](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/606743/biggest-upvoters).

You can certainly find similar queries (or create your own). If you are interested in other data related to voting, you might also have a look at other questions [tagged statistics+voting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics+voting).

Comment: I've up-voted this answer. Your "percentage of downvotes" query doesn't list users by raw number of down-votes. Also, a less crude thing that restriction to those above a certain reputation would be a ratio  of up-votes or down-votes to reputation. Maybe if I can't figure out how to phrase useful queries, I'll ask you about it.

Comment: Well, to be honest my sql skills do not go much beyond taking somebody else query and make slight modifications. But there some users very skilled in using data explorer [around here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/topusers).

Comment: @MichaelHardy 1) Open [Martin's query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/606739/biggest-downvoters). 2) Click the header of the column with the title "Downvotes". Doing that will re-sort the table according to the number of downvotes. Clicking that column again reverses the order. You can do the same with any other column.